# Posting a Header to API (Wrike) request

Tags: powershell, http-headers

I am trying to post a header as part of my `Invoke-RestMethod` request and am facing the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
Parameter name: name
```

Here is my line of code:

```
$FolderRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -uri https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders -Headers @{'Authorization: bearer '=$access_token}
```

I am doing it in the exact format as the documentation states:

[image]

Anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? I know the error is stating that something is wrong with the Name parameter, but I can't fathom what could be wrong with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colons (`:`) aren't permitted in HTTP header names because they're used to delimit the header field name from the corresponding value.

I suspect your header *should* be `@{'Authorization' =" bearer $access_token"}` If you watch the HTTP traffic, you'll see the following in the request header:

`Authorization: bearer YOURTOKEN`

Comment: Ah! Will try this first thing Monday. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: `-Headers @{'Authorization' = ' bearer '+$access_token}` did the trick